# Excel: Conditional Formatting based on combination of cell values in a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to apply conditional formatting such that it will highlight the cells green if a particular selection in combination with other cells in a drop down list are selected.

The idea is I am trying to create a simple support matrix between 5 different products and their firmware versions.

All values in the cells are numbers, eg: 6.1.

What function/s should I use for a rule?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about selection in combination kindly give an example

Comment: Let's see what you got so far. A link to an image of your Sheet. We assume you've created a drop list correctly already? That would need a vlookup probably -- what I usually use for drop list.

Comment: Hi apologies for the delay, please attached a screenshot of the spreadsheet and an example of a list I created in one cell:

Comment: [spreadsheet](http://i22.photobucket.com/albums/b350/Atb_555/Screen%201.jpg) and [cell](http://i22.photobucket.com/albums/b350/Atb_555/Screen%202.jpg)

Comment: I have tried the following formulas: **1.** AND(($B$6="6.10")+($C$6="8.10")+($D$6="6.2.4")+($E$6="6.2")+($F$6="6.0.2")+($G$6="3.3.2"))  **2.** =AND($B$6=6.10,$C$6=8.10,$D$6=6.2.4,$E$6=6.2,$F$6=6.0.2,$G$6=3.3.2)  **3.** =AND($B$6=6.10)+($C$6=8.10)+($D$6=6.2.4)+($E$6=6.2)+($F$6=6.0.2)+($G$6=3.3.2)